# Is platform event limits considered for every 24 hours or hourly?

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api, pubsublwc

I am bit confused on the period considered for event limits. As per the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) the 250K limit(Unlimited) is for 24 hr rolling period

[image]

But when i see check the object that gives the limits for the events its called "HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents" and i get the correct result from query it from Rest API as below

[image]

The [documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_platform_event_publish_limits_api.htm) around this object says "High-volume platform event notifications published per hour" and lists them as 250K, i see this counter is getting refreshed every hour.

So is the limit of 250K events applied to a 24 hr window or a hourly window, seem to be hourly but the documentation says its a daily limit. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

The daily limit is the number of events which can be *delivered externally* (off platform). The hourly limit is the number of events you can publish regardless of subscribers.